# Python 3.X: Implement returnGreater() function using a list of integers and a value

Tags: python-3.x, list, for-loop, if-statement, integer

The function must return a list consisting of the numbers greater than the second number in the function
It must be able to do the following when functioning:

```
returnGreater([1,2,3,4,5], 3)
[4,5]

returnGreater([-8,2,-4,1,3,-5],3)
 []
```

Here's what I have (I've gone through a few iterations), though I get a Type Error for trying to use a ">" symbol between an int and list:

```
def returnGreater (x,y):
    "x:list(int) , return:list(int)"
    #greater: int
    greater = []
    for y in x:
        #x: int
        if x > y:
            x = greater
    return greater
```

Comment: What's your question? You seem to understand the error. `if x > y:` doesn't make sense if `x` is a list.

Comment: And this could be done trivially with `filter`.

Comment: I have to do it without filter

Answer (score 0):

You're using the name `y` for two different things in your code. It's both an argument (the number to compare against) and the loop variable. You should use a different name for one of those.

I'd strongly suggest picking *meaningful* names, as that will make it much clearer what each variable means, as well as making it much less likely you'll use the same name for two different things. For instance, here's how I'd name the variables (getting rid of both `x` and `y`):

```
def returnGreater(list_of_numbers, threshold):
    greater = []
    for item in list_of_numbers:
        if item > threshold:
            greater.append(item)
    return greater
```

You had another issue with the line `x = greater`, which didn't do anything useful (it replaced the reference to the original list with a reference to the empty `greater` list. You should be `append`ing the item you just compared to the `greater` list instead.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend `filter`. Easy and Graceful way.

```
def returnGreater(x, y):
    return list(filter(lambda a:a>y, x))
```

It means, filter each element `a` in list `x` using `lambda` whether `a` is greater than `y` or not.

Answer (score 0):

[List Comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

```
def returnGreater(_list, value):
    return [x for x in _list if x > value]
```